# XML XPATH based on atribute and value as filter

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have the following XML

```
<tickerfeed version="2.4">
    <playlist type="flipping_carousel" name="Ctl_Foreign" target="carousel">
        <element>
            <template>Ctl_Foreign</template>
            <field name="foreign_stock">DJI</field>
            <field name="price">31301.66</field>
            <field name="arrow">2</field>
        </element>
        <element>
            <template>Ctl_Foreign</template>
            <field name="foreign_stock">SPX</field>
            <field name="price">3918.92</field>
            <field name="arrow">2</field>
        </element>
        <element>
            <template>Ctl_Foreign</template>
            <field name="foreign_stock">COMP</field>
            <field name="price"/>
            <field name="arrow">3</field>
        </element>
    </playlist>
</tickerfeed>
```

How can I filter the based on field name="foreign_stock" that has value "SPX" and get all the rest
fields of "element" node?

for example, to filter only the:

```
<template>Ctl_Foreign</template>
<field name="foreign_stock">SPX</field>
<field name="price">3918.92</field>
<field name="arrow">2</field>
```

I know that need to use somthing like
/tickerfeed/playlist/element/field[@name='foreign_stock' and xyz]

but how to combine a search on attribute and the value together. What to write in xyz part or XPath?

Thanks in advance for your help
EG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following XPath expression:

```
/tickerfeed/playlist/element[field[@name="foreign_stock"]/text()="SPX"]/*
```